# Can't find modules' and services' paths

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest with Angular 15. I have followed all their setup guide and got the most basic tests running. Now I created some component which uses services.

This is the basic test for `alert.service.spec.ts` code:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AlertService } from '@app/core/services/topics/alert.service';

describe('AlertService', () => {
  let service: AlertService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(AlertService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and I get this error:

```
 FAIL  src/app/core/services/alert.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/app/core/services/alert.service.spec.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@app/core/services/topics/alert.service' or its corresponding type declarations.

    3 import { AlertService } from '@app/core/services/topics/alert.service';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I configured the `@app` path because it seems that you have to tell Jest where to find stuff. So in `package.json` I have:

```
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/config.jest.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns":
    [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
      "@src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  }
```

and in `tsconfig.specs.json` I have:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
    "@src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?